# Handling release.keystore while uploading android library to jitpack

Tags: android, gradle, jitpack

I was trying to publish a snapshot of a branch as a jitpack library, but during the build (initiated by jitpack) this error comes up in the logs when I click on `get` in the jitpack website.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':openmrs-client:validateSigningRelease'.

> Keystore file '/home/jitpack/build/release.keystore' not found for signing config 'release'.

I saw the build.gradle file as far as I can understand the release build depends upon the environment variables in travis. then how do I upload this snapshot to jitpack library?
I have seen most of the tutorials but none of them covers up this case :(

settings.gradle

```
include ':openmrs-android-sdk'
include ':openmrs-client'
```

build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.72'
    ext.safeargs_version = '2.3.0'
    System.properties['com.android.build.gradle.overrideVersionCheck'] = 'true'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$safeargs_version"
        classpath "com.hiya:jacoco-android:0.2"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

app level build.gradle

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots'}
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.triplet.gradle:play-publisher:2.2.1'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.github.triplet.play' version '2.2.1'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'

    // TODO AC-861
    //id 'jacoco-android'
    id 'com.hiya.jacoco-android'
}
apply from: './versions.gradle'
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs"

def version = versions.appVersion
def GOOGLE_PLACE_API_KEY = System.getenv('GOOGLE_PLACE_API_KEY') ?: "YOUR_API_KEY"

android {
    compileSdkVersion versions.compileSdk

    def travisBuildNumber = System.getenv("TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER")
    def buildNumber = (travisBuildNumber) ? (travisBuildNumber as int) : 1

    def applicationVersion = version
    def travisTag = System.getenv("TRAVIS_TAG")
    def buildVersionName = (travisTag) ? travisTag : applicationVersion + "-debug." + buildNumber

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.openmrs.mobile"
        versionName buildVersionName
        versionCode buildNumber
        multiDexEnabled true

        minSdkVersion versions.minSdk
        targetSdkVersion versions.targetSdk

        testApplicationId "org.openmrs.mobile.test"
        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'

        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
        manifestPlaceholders = [
                GOOGLE_PLACE_API_KEY: GOOGLE_PLACE_API_KEY
        ]
    }

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile rootProject.file('release.keystore')
            storePassword System.getenv("KEYSTORE_PASSWORD")
            keyAlias System.getenv("KEYSTORE_ALIAS_NAME")
            keyPassword System.getenv("KEYSTORE_ALIAS_PASS")
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled true
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        warning 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            returnDefaultValues = true
            includeAndroidResources = true
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'http://yanzm.github.io/MaterialTabHost/repository' }
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    google()
}

dependencies {

    // Android sdk library dependency
    implementation project(path: ':openmrs-android-sdk')
  
    //more dependencies....
}
```

library module build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    dependencies {

           //.. some dependencies..
    }

    afterEvaluate {
        publishing {
            publications {
                release(MavenPublication) {
                    from components.release

                    groupId = 'com.openmrs.AndroidSDK'
                    artifactId = 'final'
                    version = '1.0.0'
                }
    
                debug(MavenPublication) {
                    from components.debug

                    groupId = 'com.openmrs.AndroidSDK'
                    artifactId = 'final-debug'
                    version = '1.0.0'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```